# SVG from PHP script is not working in img src

Tags: php, image, svg, yii2, src

I'm trying to open SVG file first in PHP and then return this data:

```php
$file = dirname(__FILE__) . $_GET["file"] . ".svg";

if (!file_exists($file)) {
    $file = dirname(__FILE__) . $_GET["file"] . ".png";
    if (!file_exists($file)) {
        throw new NotFoundHttpException();
    } else
        header('Content-Type: image/png');
} else
    header('Content-Type: image/svg+xml');

$content = file_get_contents($file);
return $content;
```

And in HTML:

```html
<img src="script.php?file=someimage">
```

Problem is that its not showing SVG images in the tag. It works, if I set `script.php?file=someimage` to the URL string of my browser, but not inside the tag. PNG works fine. If i set just

```html
<img src="someimage.svg">
```

it also works perfect.

embed and object tags works, but I need img.

**UPDATE:**

The problem was in Yii2, I send headers wrong way. In some reason it works for PNG, but not for SVG.

It should be done like that:

```php
Yii::$app->response->format = \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_RAW;
Yii::$app->response->headers->add('Content-Type', 'image/svg+xml');
```

Comment: Is your html and php hosted in same server?  Also can you try an `object` instead of `img` Example - `<object data="script.php?file=someimage" type="image/svg+xml"></object>`

Comment: Its on my own server. Yeah, as i mentioned object tag is working, but as you see, i'm checking if svg file exist and if not, i return PNG file. So it would be nice to use img tag. I have no idea why <img src="file.svg"> is working, but <img src="/?file=file.svg> - not.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you forgot the `/`. Try replacing these lines where appropriate:

```php
$file = dirname(__FILE__) . '/' . $_GET["file"] . ".svg";
// ...
$file = dirname(__FILE__) '/' . $_GET["file"] . ".png";
```

`dirname()` gives back a string without a trailing slash, so it was trying to open `/path/to/scriptdirsomefile.svg`.

### Security

Also, I noticed that your script can be made to do bad things, such as exposing arbitrary files on the server. You can prevent a lot of exploits by doing some basic sanitizing of `$_GET['file']` before starting:

```php
$_GET['file'] = preg_replace('#/#', '_', $_GET['file']);
```

Comment: Thanks, but the path is correct, it works with PNG files, also it works with SVG files if I put this URL into address field of the browser, but it doesn't work in src="" tag.

Comment: $_GET['file'] = preg_replace('#/#', '_', $_GET['file']); - But it's a good point.

Answer (score 0):

Change `return $content;` to `echo $content;`

So if the image files are on the same directory, it will be:

```
<?php
$file =  $_GET["file"] . ".svg";

if (!file_exists($file)) {
    $file =  $_GET["file"] . ".png";
    if (!file_exists($file)) {
        throw new NotFoundHttpException();
    } else
        header('Content-Type: image/png');
} else
    header('Content-Type: image/svg+xml');

$content = file_get_contents($file);
echo $content;
?>
```

Working example #1 (showing svg):

http://www.createchhk.com/SOanswers/subc/index.php

Working example #2 (showing png):

http://www.createchhk.com/SOanswers/subc/index2.php

Comment: Nope, it does not work. it was echo first there, its a part of YII2 action method, so return at this case is same as echo.

Comment: Did you check the sandbox link which successfully displays the svg ?

Comment: Yes! Its working on your side. It's great. But its not on mine. :(

Comment: I set echo back, same result.

Comment: But you helped me, as I see that it works in another environment. Thanks!

Comment: Good that you find it working in another environment. Have a nice day. (I have added another sandbox link showing the png . You may right click both links to see the source codes.)

Comment: Great, but on my side PNG is working, but SVG is not. I'm confused. Anyway, thanks for help.